# next-pwa set pwa homepage to subdirectory

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

I need my PWA to open at /app instead of /.  It opens at / and offers the install prompt even with my configuration below.

Am I missing some configuration aside from start_url ?

**next.config.js**

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");
const runtimeCaching = require("next-pwa/cache");
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = withPWA({
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    runtimeCaching,
    scope: "/app/",
  },
});
```

**/public/manifest.json** --shortened colors and icons

```
{
  "theme_color": "#",
  "background_color": "#",
  "display": "standalone",
  "start_url": "/app/",
  "scope": "/app/",
  "name": "",
  "short_name": "",
  "icons": [...]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried also setting the `basePath: "/app"` property in [`next.config.js`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/basepath)?